# What is the fastest way to compare strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, string-comparison

I have two strings and I need to know whether they are equal.

I have previously done this: str1 === str2 , but I wonder if there is a faster way to compare two strings.

The strings are fairly short being 15-25 characters long. My problem is that I am iterating through a lot of strings and it is taking quite a long time.

I have a lot of comparisons in a structure like this:

```
If(str === str1)
{
  do something
}
else if(str === str2)
{
  do something
}
else if(str === str3)
{
  do something
}
```

The strings do not have any common structure or grouping.

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: how long are the strings? if they are too long you can hash them and compare their hashes

Comment: Yeah, but hashing them implies visiting every character of each string, computing the hash, THEN comparing the hashes. Hard to see that will be faster than just a direct comparison.

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting this ? It could have been an interesting question.

Comment: why do you need something that is faster ? It really depends on your problem and nature of those strings.

Comment: @DavidW if you need to repeat the comparison and you can save/cache the hash-strings, then it's gonna be faster, in other cases you're absolutely right ...

Comment: @Mahdi Perfectly valid point - I think the OP needs to clarify the scope of the question to that end.

Comment: "My problem is that I am iterating through a lot of strings and it is taking quite a long time." You should have said this before. Testing for a match against one of multiple strings allows for lots of different solutions that aren't possible when simply testing a random pair of strings. To get a proper answer though you should post the code, or at least an outline of it, because it's still not clear what you mean.

Comment: It's taking a long time for you to write the comparisons or for the code to run?

Comment: You may reuse ```localeCompare``` for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comparing strings with `a === b` is the fastest way to compare string natives.

However, if you could create String Objects like `new String("test")`, re-use those and use those in the comparisons, that would be even faster, because the JS engine would only need to do a pointer-comparison, which is (a small amount) faster than string comparisons.

See http://jsperf.com/string-vs-object-comparisons

Comment: That is an interesting idea. Thanks

Comment: Because the JS engine may optimize by string interning.

Comment: This does not test the value of the string, just the location of string in memory `new String("apple") === new String("apple")` equals `false`

Comment: Yes, that's why "re-use those" is key here. You shouldn't create new ones, but re-use the existing ones, e.g. using a map of sorts.

Comment: In which case you don't need a string at all. Any normal object would do. If you do want to use a string the I'd suggest making it a `Symbol`. That's what symbols are meant for.

Comment: The question is about Strings, so whether pointer comparison works for other objects doesn't matter :-) Thanks for pointing out Symbol; didn't know about those!

Answer (score 3):

If your "do somethings" share a similar form with different values, you can put the values into a map and use the string as a key. For example's sake, imagine you have to process many numbers with different units of length and you want to convert them all to meters:

```
var conversionToMeters = {
    "inch":   0.0254,
    "inches": 0.0254,
    "foot": 0.3048,
    "feet": 0.3048,
    "cubit":  0.4572,
    "cubits": 0.4572,
    "yard":  0.9144,
    "yards": 0.9144,
    "kilometer":  1000,
    "kilometers": 1000,
    "mile":  1609.344,
    "miles": 1609.344,
    "lightyear":  9.46e15,
    "lightyears": 9.46e15,
    "parsec":  3.09e16,
    "parsecs": 3.09e16,
}
```

(Abbreviations (like "km") and international spellings (like "kilometres") omitted for brevity.) You can prepare that map ahead of time to avoid creation overhead. Now, given a variable `length` such as `length = "80 miles"`, you can do:

```
var magnitude = length.replace(/[\D]/g, "");
var unit = length.replace(/[\d\s]/g, "");
var lengthInMeters = magnitude * conversionToMeters[unit];
alert(lengthInMeters + " meters"); // Ta-da!
```

If your "do somethings" do not share common code you can still use a map, but it will be a map of functions:

```
var actions = {
    "eat": function() {
        if (spareFood > 0) {
            spareFood--;
            energy += 10;
            health++;
            alert("Yum!");
        }
    },
    "walk": function() {
        if (energy > 0) energy--;
        // ...
    },
    "attack": function() {
        if (energy > 0) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.25) {
                health--;
                alert("Ouch!");
            }
            energy--;
        }
    },
    // ...
};
```

This is a bit of a silly example but I hope it explains the basic idea. The actions could equally be XML tags, or names of CPU instructions in a virtual machine, or names of products that have special shipping requirements, or whatever. Once you've got your `action` variable, executing it is as simple as:

```
actions[action]();
```

A map isn't the only way to do this kind of thing. Your original if/else example can be optimized easily by nesting the ifs inside additional ifs that are **designed to quickly eliminate most of the candidate strings**.

The criteria you branch on will depend on the exact strings you're working with. It could be the length of the string, or the first letter, or a couple of the most distinguishing letters:

```
if (str.length === 3) {
    // test all length 3 strings here
    if (str === strA) doSomething();
    else if (str == strB) doSomething();
} else if (str.length === 4) {
    // test all length 4 strings here
    if (str === strC) doSomething();
    else if (str === strD) doSomething();
}
```

Or:

```
var first = str[0]; // first character
if (first >= "0" && first <= "9") {
    // test all strings that start with digits here
if (first >= "a" && first <= "l") {
    // test all strings that start with letters
    // in the first half of the alphabet here
} else if (first >= "m" && first <= "z") {
    // test all strings that start with letters
    // in the latter half of the alphabet here
}
```

You can nest these kind of tests inside one another to whatever degree is appropriate to sift through the particular strings you're working with. This is a sort of unrolled [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), although the criteria you branch on do not have to divide the candidate strings into exactly two groups.

Also, when you use an if/elseif like this, it's often worth arranging the strings in descending order of frequency. I.e., test the ones that happen most, first. If there are just a couple of strings that make up the majority of the data, pull them to the top, and even put them outside of any pre-tests based on length or first letter.

You'll have to decide whether it's worth doing these things: if you take these techniques to the extreme, you might be able to squeeze tiny additional performance benefits, but it will sacrifice readability and maintainability.

P.S. I don't know JavaScript well enough to know exactly how these techniques will perform but I've done similar things in Java. In Java the map approach is unbeatable when the "do somethings" require different values but can use the same code. In a different program, I needed to `switch` on an integer value performing about 400 dissimilar actions (it was awful). The HotSpot Client VM has a lousy inefficient implementation of the `switch` statement that is simply a lot of elseifs, and it was too slow. An array of functions (which technically were objects with overridden virtual methods) was faster, but the function call overhead was too great compared to the simplicity of each action. In this case I found a mixed binary-quaternary search to be effective. What that means is: the outer tests were if/elses that divided the input values evenly into two groups. These were nested until there were only four possible values left in the inner groups. Then I used an if/elseif/elseif/else to distinguish among the remaining four values. Since this was so long, I wrote some code to write it for me, but it was still worth the effort for this particular application.

P.P.S. There's an approach I skipped above but I'll include it for completeness: if your strings will rarely need changing, you can use a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). There are utility programs that design these functions for you: just supply them with a list of all your strings. A perfect hash function will calculate an integer hashcode from a string, and guarantee that no two strings from your set have the same hashcode. Then you can use the integer hashcode for lookup of the action in an array. It's helpful for things like parsing keywords of programming languages. It can be faster in a language that is closer to the metal, but in JavaScript I suspect it will not be worth it. I'm mentioning it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest V8 way would be to use a switch statement like so:

```js
var str = '' + prompt('Enter cat or enter in dog');
switch(''+str){ // make it clear you are switching on a string
  case 'cat':
    console.log('you selected cat!');
    break;
  case 'dog':
    console.log('you selected dog!');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('you selected something else!');
}
```

The reason for why this is the fastest way is because it will give the JIT optimizer more opportunity to optimize the comparisons. For example, one possible optimization it may perform is to preemptively search for a string of the same length starting with the same character before it does any actual comparisons.

However, if you do those if-else comparisons, then the JIT optimizer may or may not be able to optimize those comparisons into something as efficient.

The reason for why allowing the JIT optimizer to perform its own optimizations on the switch statement can be faster is because when it is just comparing the length, it will be able to sort the lengths of the strings it compares. This will make the numerical length comparison much much faster (see [Proccessing Sorted VS Unsorted Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)).

Comment: What is a "JIST optimizer"?

Answer (score 1):

I already did a benchmark trough https://jsbench.me/. These where the results:

[image]

So, as [Jack Giffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5601591/jack-giffin) said, switch syntax is the fastest in this case. If you are doing negative comparators, then the results change:

[image]